# "в теории" против "на практике"

Tags: предлоги

The complementary concepts "in theory" and "in practice" are expressed in Russian with different prepositions: **в** теории and **на** практике. Perhaps there is no good explanation of that, but if someone could provide any reason why the same preposition is not used in both phrases I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think reasons are purely euphonic (good sounding). All four combinations are attested in older texts.

Comment: @Quassnoi,  are в теории and на практике better sounding than на теории or в практике only because you are used to them?  Thanks for telling me that all the possibilities have been used in the past.

Comment: I'm theorizing here, but *впр* is a little bit hard to pronounce, and while the Russian can cope with it if there is no grammatical substitute for it (like in _в предыстории_) they would still enjoy an extra syllable within a consonant cluster every now and then, if they are free to choose the preposition. Note that _в моей практике_ is still used with _в_.

Comment: @Quassnoi Note that you can't say *на моей практике*, while *случай в практике* is very much extant. Also, consider *во сне* vs. *наяву*.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: that's a good point too.

Comment: @Quassnoi actually, I'm in the middle of having an epiphany: could there be a consistent в/на dichotomy that is ultimately an indoors/outdoors metaphor (*в доме/на улице*)? I've also thought of *в тени* vs. *на свету*. I suppose it's too speculative to include in my answer that's alreadly overedited.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: how would you falsify that hypothesis? You can tell of pretty much anything it used to be perceived as a confined space in the past but not now, and vice versa. Just consider *в поле* or *в космосе*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**На практике** is probably modelled after **на деле**, and is a more abstract use of the *на* that is more or less grammaticalised as the "at" preposition for organised activities: *на работе*, *на уборке урожая*, *на вечеринке*, etc.

(Edit: or, now that I think of it, it may be something else: Russian may implicitly regard "unreal"/mental spaces as enclosed, and "real"/physical ones as open. Best illustrated by **во сне** vs. **наяву**.)

As for not using the same preposition — Russian essentially shrugs it off. Remember that the Russian multi-paradigm declension means that a speaker gets used to forming sequences of entirely different morphemes meaning exactly the same thing, e.g.

> В лесу мы видели еж**ей**, куниц[-Ø]  и барсук**ов**

— and that sense of equivalence in difference may carry over to prepositions. Speculatively, I even sometimes feel that **в** and **на** used with the prepositional case in a locative sense have come, subjectively, to be perceived as the front part of a circumfix, rather than a "detachable" preposition.

(That may also be a subtle yet powerful influence the **на Украине/в Украине** controversy, since for many people, using a different preposition would *feel* like an intervention into the deepest workings of grammar itself, rather than word choice.)

Comment: Куда ни сунься, везде про Украину, даже на stackexchange )))

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это вы в такой момент зашли. До прошлого раза скроллить и скроллить.

Answer (score 0):

I will also add a hypothesis that *в теории* is compared to sources of information like *в книгах, в рукописях, в идеях, в мыслях*, while *на практике* is like *на работе, на деле, на месте, на объекте, на задании* and refers to actually being on location and physically encountering some situation.

Answer (score -2):

"na" literally translates to the english word on. like powering "on"

the letter B (pronounced VVV) means in.

so the Russians for reasons unknown to science have two ways of saying it. Both or correct you could say "в теории и в практике" (in theory and in practice) and they would both be correct for some reason. At this point it does not necessarily make a difference which word you choose people will understand you. however saying you are "на туалете" is strange but "на Украине" is correct... but "на России" is wrong..... so when talking about a location best use "v" (or in Russian alphabet  B), whichever you choose V is your safe option.